CKEditor convert any html tag to other format (BBCode format)
I using CKEditor, but recently I have a problem after receiving a new update.
When using any HTML tags, CKEditor changes the tags like the following example:
<b> becomes [b]
or
<p> convert [p]

sample:
hi Ali => hi [b]Ali[/b]
This is what I want it to be: hi <b>Ali</b>
I could not find any documentation about this, Can you help me?

Have you any plugin installed for template languages?

I solved the problem:
just disable BBCode Output Format plugin!
BBCode Output Format

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
